# Как сделать чтоб NavigationView не затеняла основной экран

Tags: android, android-navigation-view

Добрый день.
При открытии NavigationView основной экран затеняется, можно ли как нибудь отключить этот эффект?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31570265/3212712) надо так:

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Comment: как доктор прописал. Спасибо.